# How can I modify an element's value in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-3.9

I am trying to marginally increment a value in a one-by-n numpy array. However python doesn't seem to change the value at all. No errors are thrown (apart from elsewhere in the program when the return is unexpectedly zero).

```py
def numerical_partial_derivative(f, x, i, dx = delta):
    print("delta:", delta)
    print("x type:", type(x))
    x_bip = x
    x_bop = x
    x_bip[i] = x_bip[i] + delta
    x_bop[i] = x_bop[i] - delta

    print("x, x_bip, x_bop:", x, x_bip, x_bop)

    return ((f(x_bip) - f(x_bop)) / (2 * dx))
```

But my output when this function is called is (regardless of whatever dx value I use):

```
delta: 1
x type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
x, x_bip, x_bop: [-2.  2.] [-2.  2.] [-2.  2.]
```

How can this be? It doesn't work calling the code directly or in an ipython notebook.
I have similar problems elsewhere, where a numpy array refuses to accept new values.

Comment: What arguments do you use here? And what output do you expect? Your function would be easier to understand for us if you use descriptive variable names instead of single letter variables.

Comment: Assigning variables doesn't make copies of the arrays. `x`, `x_bip`, and `x_bop` are all the same array.

Comment: `x_bip = x.copy()`